# "Operating" on objects

Tags: c++, oop

I have an object that contains, as part of its data, a linked list. Let's call this object LL, for reference sake.

I want to apply what I will call "operators" to instances of LL. So, an operator will, for instance, swap two elements of LL's linked list.

Ordinarily one might put such operators as methods of LL (so, you'd call `LL.swap()` or whatever) but I want to be able to define new types of operators.

The obvious thing to do, it seems to me, is to define an "Operator" class of objects that accept a pointer to an LL object when constructed. You could then call `Operator.go()` which would perform the swap.

However, this just doesn't seem right to me (for vague reasons I'm finding hard to articulate).

Other salient facts include:

1. I will want to perform many of these operations in sequence (so perhaps the overhead should be as low as possible).
2. There will usually only be a small number of LL objects instantiated.

Is defining an "Operator" class the way to go?  Am I crazy for thinking it should be otherwise? The problem is: I'm having trouble imagining what "otherwise" might be. I haven't done any programming in a while and I'm slow in re-adjusting my brain to it.

Comment: Naming a class like a C++ keyword (case apart) is IMO a very bad idea. That being apart, do you know what the STL is about, what functors are and what `std::transform` provides?

Comment: A free function is the common approach. It can even be templated for maximum generality. The downside is that you can only use the class's public interface.

Comment: Instead of using a special method for the operator classes, just overload the `operator()` method?

Comment: @Benoit: And do _you_ know that the STL has no `std` namespace? And to which keyword are you referring?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: `operator`. Also I have read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571) several times.

Comment: @Benoit: Where is it suggested that the type will be called `operator`? Touché on the other bit ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: *“The obvious thing to do, it seems to me, is to define an "Operator" class of objects”*

Comment: @Benoit: point taken.  I would probably not name anything "Operator" when it comes to implementation.

Comment: @Joachim: I envision having many different operators acting on the same object.

Comment: @Benoit: `Operator` and `operator` are not the same sequence of characters. [edit: I just noticed you _did_ say "case apart". Oops.]

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: That's why I said “case apart” in my first comment!

Comment: Hmm ok, I thought you were going to one operator class per operation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Using a "free function" seems to go against the grain when using the OO paradigm, but perhaps it is the best way to go.  (Although Bjorn's suggestion of visitor-patterns below might what I want).

Comment: @BobHeffernan: Well, lucky us then that C++ doesn't force a single paradigm down our throats :-) Have you checked out the standard library? It's full of free functions left right and centre. The best solution is often the one that reflects your needs and design most accurately and naturally, and not necessarily the one that's object oriented to the extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have thought of there is called the [visitor-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and it is a good and flexible way to add behavior to objects.

Comment: ... where "good" and "flexible" are very relative :-) Alexandrescu says that the visitor pattern is terrible and ugly, but that it sometimes can be the right tool -- it depends very much on the nature of the code base. In general, it's appropriate when the class hierarchy is very stable and you just want to add new behaviour a lot.

Comment: This may be exactly what I want (even taking @KerrekSB's comments into account).